# Why does the script not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make an on-click div appear draggable div. Searched the right javascript in Google but when I copied it to my html then it does not work. Could someone please explain why and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <link type="text/css"href="./Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/javascript"href="./Style.js" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <span class="about" id="but01">Click on me 1</span>
    <span class="about" id="but02">Click on me 2</span>

    <div id="s1" class="hidden" id="draggable-element">
        <div id="draggable-element">Text here</div>
    </div>

    <div id="s2" class="hidden">2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body{
background-color: #101010;
color: #ff9900;
}

.hidden{
    display:none;
}

[draggable=true] {
    cursor: move;
}
#draggable-element {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#ff9900;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 12px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative; /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

The JS:

```
    $('span[id^="but0"]').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
            if($('#s' + id).is(':visible'))
                 $('#s' + id).hide();
            else
                $('#s' + id).show();
    });

var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;+
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: It seems to work for me. The first outputs an draggable element and the other the number 2. [I tested it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJogzz)

Comment: I see there are 2 `<div>` has attribute `id="draggable-element"`: `<div id="s1" class="hidden" id="draggable-element">` and `<div id="draggable-element">Text here</div>`. Maybe error comes on these, try to remove one of them and tell me this works or not

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of `<link type="text/javascript"href="./Style.js" rel="stylesheet">`? It’s neither a stylesheet nor would you `link` JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `+` sign at the end of the last line. By removing it, I see it working as in the example below.

```
document.onmouseup = _destroy;+
```

Here is the example:

```js
$('span[id^="but0"]').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
  if ($('#s' + id).is(':visible'))
    $('#s' + id).hide();
  else
    $('#s' + id).show();
});

var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
  x_pos = 0,
  y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
  x_elem = 0,
  y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
  // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
  selected = elem;
  x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
  y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
  x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
  y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
  if (selected !== null) {
    selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
    selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
  }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
  selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function() {
  _drag_init(this);
  return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
  color: #ff9900;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
[draggable=true] {
  cursor: move;
}
#draggable-element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
  /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span class="about" id="but01">Click on me 1</span>
<span class="about" id="but02">Click on me 2</span>

<div id="s1" class="hidden" id="draggable-element">
  <div id="draggable-element">Text here</div>
</div>

<div id="s2" class="hidden">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
<link type="text/javascript"href="./Style.js" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<script src='./Style.js' >
```